# Customizing json rendering for sling's userManager

Tags: json, jackrabbit, sling

I am trying to build my application's admin UI using sling's userManager REST interface, but I would like to customize the json rendering. For example, I would like the response of ["Get group"](http://sling.apache.org/site/managing-users-and-groups-jackrabbitusermanager.html#Managingusersandgroups%2528jackrabbit.usermanager%2529-Getgroup) to  include the members only if the requestor is a member.

I started by adding libs/sling/group/json.esp but I don't understand how I can get hold of the default response and customize it. Even if I had to query and form the json from scratch, where can I find information about APIs available to get this data from JCR/Sling?

I found that I could use ResourceTraversor to dump the resource object in json form but using new Packages.org.apache.sling.servlets.get.impl.helpers.ResourceTraversor(-1, 10000, resource, true) in the esp throws up an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to note here.

First, you should avoid putting your code under the `libs` directory.  Your app code should live under the `apps` directory.  When attempting to resolve a servlet for a URI, Sling will check `apps` before it checks `libs` so if you need to completely override functionality delivered with Sling, you would place your code in `apps`.

Second, what is (probably, depending on how you have things setup) happening when you request `http://localhost:8080/system/userManager/group/administrators.tidy.1.json` is the request is being handled by Sling's default GET servlet, because it finds no other script or servlet which is applicable.  For research purposes it might be worth looking at the code for the default get servlet, `org.apache.sling.servlets.get.impl.DefaultGetServlet`, to see what it's using to render JSON.  If you need to handle the rendering of a user group in a manner different than what the default GET servlet is doing, then you would need to create a servlet which is listening for requests for resources of type `sling/group`.  It would probably be ideal to create a servlet for this purpose and register it with OSGI.  http://sling.apache.org/site/servlets.html provides the various properties you would need to set to ensure the servlet resolver finds your servlet. Your servlet then would handle the request and as such would have direct and easy access to the requested resource.

Third, the particular need you specified is that you do not want the group members to render unless the requesting user is a member of the group requested.  This is more of an access control issue than a rendering issue.  Sling and Jackrabbit, out of the box, make as few assumptions as possible concerning how you might want your application to be setup.  That being the case, you need to establish the access controls that are applicable for your particular use case.  The wiki post on Access Control in the Jackrabbit wiki ( http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/AccessControl ) goes into this to an extent.

Comment: Note that a script would also work (scripts and servlets are equivalent in Sling) and might be more convenient for experimenting. If you add a script at apps/sling/group/json.esp for example, requesting a group as /system/userManager/group/newGroupA.json will use it. That overrides the default representation though, if that's not desired you can hook the script to a selector by naming it custom.json.esp for example, and it would only be active if the group is requested as /system/userManager/group/newGroupA.custom.json

Answer (score 0):

Using directions from Paul Michelotti's answer, I researched further and found a suitable solution to my problem.

Sling accepts request filters (javax.servlet.Filter) through SCR annotations like the one below

```
@SlingFilter(scope = SlingFilterScope.REQUEST, order = Integer.MIN_VALUE)
```

Every request is passed down to the filter before it is processed by the servlet. Using the resourceType, I was able to distinguish requests to group.1.json and group/mygroup.1.json. Since the filter also has access to the current user, I was able to decide to deny the request if it did not abide by my security model and return a 404 status code.

Please refer to [this page](http://sling.apache.org/site/filters.html) for details on filters. You can also check out the sample project [urlfilter](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/samples/urlfilter) for directions on usage.