# Listening to changes in sling's users and groups

Tags: jackrabbit, sling

I want to be notified of changes to users or groups in sling's userManager as they happen. For example, when a new group is created, I need to create a new node with the same name under /content. When a new user is created, I want to give them write-permissions for /content/foo. And similar tearDown steps when objects are deleted.

I tried registering a EventHandler (org.osgi.service.event.EventHandler), with event.topics set to "*" (all topics), but this captured only resource changes and not userManager changes because users and groups are synthetic resources (I think)

I tried using a org.apache.sling.api.request.SlingRequestListener, but the SlingRequestEvent did not come with any info that would help me distinguish the request (or I didn't know how). Also, I am not sure if this is can even be used for callbacks that need to be called AFTER the request is processed.

I have used [Filters](http://sling.apache.org/site/filters.html) for a [different issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924035/customizing-json-rendering-for-slings-usermanager) and I tried applying them for this purpose too. But they have their limitations - My filter is called BEFORE the request, so it's not possible to know if the request will result in SUCCESS before deciding to take action.

Any suggestions on how to listen and respond to changes in sling's user and group models?

Comment: We covered this in a class that I attended a few months ago.  I don't understand it well enough to provide a worked example.  But I can suggest the ObservationManager, Event, and EventListener in the [javax.jcr.observation](http://www.day.com/maven/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-1.0/javax/jcr/observation/package-summary.html) package.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. But, I suspect that it might not work with Users and Groups because they are not true JCR nodes

Answer (score 1):

In https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-977 Ian Boston suggests using a SlingPostProcessor service to be informed of calls to the user management's POST servlets.

I haven't tried it myself, and if you do it you might anyway miss changes that are done via Sling's user management APIs - but that might be good enough depending on your use case.

Apart from that I don't think there's currently a surefire way of being notified of such changes. To implement that in Sling we'd need to wrap the org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.user.* objects (Group, User, UserManager) to send events when they're changed. Certainly doable but would require changes to that Sling bundle.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I tried adding a post-processor and a post-operation as described in the samples, but they get invoked only for POSTs going to `/content`, not to the POSTs going out to create users and groups. When I looked into the code, it seems that `SlingPostServlet` does include post-processors, but `CreateUserServlet` does not seem to use post-processors. Any chance that a recent refactoring took away the workaround you mention?